# Multiplicar elementos de um array por peso 2 e armazenar o resultado dentro de outro array

Tags: javascript, array

Estou batendo a cabeça em algo que para muitos é simples.
Estou tentando multiplicar os números contidos dentro de um array em JavaScript pelo fator 2, e salvar o resultado em outro array com todos os elementos multiplicados do array anterior.

O código que estou trabalhando é o seguinte:

```
var numeros = [2, 3, 5, 6, 8];
var nume = [];

function multiplicaPorDois (numeros) {
    for (var indice in numeros) {
        indice * 2;
        nume.push(indice);
        console.log(nume);
    }

}

multiplicaPorDois(numeros);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não use o laço [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) para iterar sobre arrays, a finalidade desse laço é iterar sobre propriedades enumeradas de um objeto.
Para iterar sobre objetos iterativos, [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set),..., use o laço [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) que é específico para iterar coleções.

Nesse trecho...

```
indice * 2;
nume.push(indice);
```

...você faz uma multiplicação porém não aproveita o resultado da operação e em seguida adiciona o valor de `indice` não multiplicado ao array `nume`.

Outra coisa que pode ser percebido é está tentando modificar uma variável externa a função e não faz uso de uma característica fundamental das funções que é a habilidade duma função ao ser finalizada [retornar valores](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) onde foi chamada.

Uma correção para o seu código seria:

```js
const numeros = [2, 3, 5, 6, 8];

function multiplicaPorDois(n) {
  let resultado = [];            //Declara uma array local que receberá os resultados.
  //Para cada elemento i do array n...
  for (let i of n) {
    resultado.push(i * 2);       //...adiciona o produto de i por 2 ao array resultado.
  }
  return resultado;              //Finaliza a função e retorna o array resultado.
}

console.log(multiplicaPorDois(numeros));
```

Outra possibilidade seria utilizar o método [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) que invoca a função callback, passada por argumento, para cada elemento do Array e devolve um novo Array como resultado.

```js
const numeros = [2, 3, 5, 6, 8];

function multiplicaPorDois(n) {
  return n.map((e) => e * 2);
}

console.log(multiplicaPorDois(numeros));
```

Ou simplemente:

```js
const numeros = [2, 3, 5, 6, 8];

console.log(numeros.map((e) => e * 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está fazendo o push do índice, enquanto deveria fazer o push do elemento do array `numeros[indice]`, passando a posição do índice para ele.

```
var numeros = [2, 3, 5, 6, 8];
var nume = [];

function multiplicaPorDois (numeros) {
  for (var indice in numeros) {
    nume.push(numeros[indice] * 2);
  }
  console.log(nume)
}

multiplicaPorDois(numeros);`
```